# Ajax issue with Chrome

Tags: ajax

I am using ajax call to append html to a jsp page from a servlet where i am outputting a string of html using response writer. The ajax call looks like this -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"form/view",
    data: "",
    cache:false,
    success:  function(data)
    {
        $("body").append(data);
    },
    error: function(data,status,xhr)
    {
        $("body").append("error ");
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    async: false,

});
```

})

The call seems to work flawlessly in firefox but appends "error" in chrome. The servlet code looks like this

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
response.setContentType("text/plain");
out.println(html);
out.close();
```

Where html is a string dynamically created from database.

Comment: is it hitting the server side in chrome? have you checked the console error? and why you've given `data:''` no need of data in case of `GET`

Comment: yes its hitting ther server side. data:' ' is one the innumerable things i tried to make this work with chrome. In chrome, instead of success, i am getting error evaluated i.e error is being appended in the body.

Comment: Is it hitting `success` or `error` callback?

Comment: error in chrome ... in firefox it's working alright

Comment: put a `debugger;` in both `success` and `error` callback function. and check where it is hitting?

Comment: interesting .... i put debugger; in both the callback functions..now its loading correctly.. i am kinda confused

Comment: have you opened the console window? Open your console window and then wait where it is hitting